# Deploying keras model with Tenserflow Serving giving error

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, data-science-model

```
I have created an classification model with Keras Deep Learning and I am exporting and saving to deploy using Tenserflow  serving but its giving below  error during starting TensorFlow Serving container step .Please suggest.below are step by steps I am doing.

**Error**: Error facing :2019-07-17 07:38:04.575012: E tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:362] FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a filesystem access error: /models/sample_test; Input/output error

**Code:**

# model creation code
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(60,input_dim=58,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(30,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train_pca, ytrain_smote,epochs=2, batch_size=10, verbose=1

config = model.get_config()
weights = model.get_weights()
new_model = model.from_config(config)
new_model.set_weights(weights)

# exporting and saving model
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import builder as saved_model_builder
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import utils
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants, signature_constants
from tensorflow.python.saved_model.signature_def_utils_impl import     build_signature_def, predict_signature_def
from tensorflow.contrib.session_bundle import exporter

export_path = 'D:\\featureTools\\deep learning\\Tenserflow Serving\\ABC
builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Model
signature = predict_signature_def(inputs={'transaction': new_model.input},
                                  outputs={'scores': new_model.output})
K.set_learning_phase(0)

with K.get_session() as sess:
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess=sess,
                                         tags=[tag_constants.SERVING],
                                         signature_def_map={'predict': signature})
    builder.save()


#Docker Image  Pull Command
docker pull tensorflow/serving

## Start TensorFlow Serving container and open the REST API port
## ABC is folder directory underwhich model file(saved_model.pb) and other folder variables is saved

docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 -v "C:\Users\sarvendra.singh\serving\tensorflow_serving\servables\tensorflow\testdata\ABC:/models/sample_test" -e MODEL_NAME=sample_test tensorflow/serving

##Error facing 
Etensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:362] FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a filesystem access error: /models/sample_test; Input/output error
```